# Why only one plot is plotted?

Tags: python, pandas

How to plot the graph between TimeStamp and Open Values?

[image: da]

I used :

```
plt.plot(copy['Timestamp'],copy['Open'])
```

but it is plotting for just one timestamp value. Here is what it plots:

[image]

Comment: You only have one value for 'Timestamp', so it's only going to plot one x value. Additionally, from what you present, the data in 'Open' is also the same. What are you expecting to get?

Comment: Actually there are more than 100,000 rows and variation of values of Open Column so I was expecting a line plot.

Comment: Are the values in 'Timestamp' different? And if so, do they have non-Nan values?

Comment: Yes they values vary and no, all the Nan values are removed.

Comment: Can you provide a small sample dataset code that reproduces the problem? It's hard to know what's going on otherwise.